# Is possible to know the path of the file of a subclass in python?

Tags: python, inheritance, plugins

I have a plugin system. The plugins subclass from a common ancestor... ad look like this:

```
-- SDK
--- basePlugin.py
-- PLUGINS
--- PluginA
---- Plugin.py
---- Config.ini
--- PluginB
---- Plugin.py
---- Config.ini
```

I need to read the info of `Config.ini` in basePlugin.py `__init__`. CUrrently in each plugin I do:

```
class PluginA(BaseSync):
  __init__(self, path):
    super(PluginA,self).__init__(self, __file__)
```

But wonder if is possible to know in the parent class in which file is located the sub-class...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming `BaseSync` is a new-style class, the parent class `BaseSync` could find the file that defines `PluginA` this way:

```
import sys
class BaseSync(object):
    def __init__(self):
        path=sys.modules[self.__module__].__file__
```

(so you don't have to pass the `path` explicitly).